# How to associate items in a JComboBox with other data?

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jcombobox

I am building an app where I print a word in different languages based on a user's selection from a JComboBox. Based on this selection, I am struggling to find a way how to associate/link items in the JComboBox with their translations into different languages. With my current implementation, I am required to hardcode all the possible outcomes.

Below is my current code:

```
public class Words {

    static Map<String, String> example1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    example1.put("english", "example");
    example1.put("chinese", "example_in_chinese");
    example1.put("arabic", "example_in_arabic");

    static Map<String, String> example2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    example2.put("english", "example2");
    example2.put("chinese", "example2_in_chinese");
    example2.put("arabic", "example2_in_arabic");
}

public class getWords {
 
     Words wordclass = new Words();
     String[] listofwords = {"example1", "example2", "example3"};
     JComboBox boxofwords= new JComboBox(listofwords);
     
    boxofwords.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
            if (boxofwords.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("example1")) {
                    System.out.println(wordclass.example1.get("english"));
                    System.out.println(wordclass.example1.get("chinese"));
                    System.out.println(wordclass.example1.get("arabic"));
            }
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: You probably would find this easier to solve if you work on your non-GUI model first, the program logic that underpins the GUI. If you have lots of 3 language groupings of words, then create a class to represent a single grouping and create a collection of them. Then build the collection using your data source, and *then* use that collection in your GUI to avoid hard-coding. Start from the basics, the model, and things will fall into place.

Comment: As I see you have two basic options.  You can seed the `JComboBox` with the "language" option and then have a translation workflow which translates the word.  Or, you associate the word and language together in POJO and use a custom cell render on the combobox display what you want

Comment: You may find the [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) class useful.  It literally exists to provide different translations based on a language setting (or more formally, based on a locale setting).